# ggplotly() does not put date on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have a plot that needs to be interactive, so I'm trying to plot it using the `ggplotly()` function. However, the x-axis gets values starting from 18k (days since 1970-01-01) instead of dates. I cannot use the normal `plotly()` function due to the plot being too complicated with different geoms that are supported by `ggplotly()` but not supported by `plotly()`. How could I get the dates on the x-axis?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(x = runif(10) + 1:10,
                   date = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-07-01"),
                                   as.Date("2020-04-01"),
                                   by = "months"))

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = x)) +
      geom_line()

ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: You can add and addition layer `scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y/%m/%d")` or whatever date format you want to `p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a scaling function

You can add a x scaling function to your plot, like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
data <- data.frame(x = runif(10) + 1:10,
                   date = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-07-01"),
                                   as.Date("2020-04-01"),
                                   by = "months"))

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = x)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y/%m/%d")
ggplotly(p)
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worth adding that this doesn't work for the older versions of `plotly` package.

Comment: The x value on the popup still doesn't work. It shows a number instead of a date.